# Imputing the median for null values using PySpark

Tags: python, median, imputation, pyspark

I have been able to successfully do exactly what I want for imputing null values using the mean. Now I want to do the identical thing for the median, here is the same code I used successfully for the mean just changed with "median" instead of "mean":

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(inputCols=df2.columns, outputCols=["{}_imputed".format(c) for c in df2.columns]

Median_Imputer = imputer.setStrategy("median").fit(df2).transform(df2).show()
Median_Imputer
```

So this prints an output (does not give an error) but the output is wrong, it does not actually calculate the median and instead seems to output the lowest value in that column as a replacement for the NaN as can be seen here:

```
Name   DateTime  Age   Name_imputed  DateTime_imputed  Age_imputed
NaN    15.0      3.5   0.5           15.0                3.5
15.0   45.0      18.0  15.0          45.0                18.0
0.5     3.5      NaN   0.5           3.5                 3.5
```

As you can see the Name column should impute 7.75 instead of 0.5 since there are 2 values and the median is just the mean of them, and for Age it should impute 10.75 instead of 3.5 (lowest value in column)

Why is this not working? It worked as needed for mean. What can be done to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work correctly if there are an odd number of filled values to compute the median from?

Comment: @Simon Crane, it appears to work correctly when there is an odd number of values that are not NAN, how do I make it work regardless of it's an odd number of even number of values (to correctly calculate the median)